# Return Max Date of a column independent of other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, maxdate

I have two tables like this:

Client Table (let's name it like ClientTable)

| ContactID | Name | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | John | johnemail01@gmail.com |
| 002 | Maria | mariaemail02@gmail.com |
| 003 | Carlos | carlosemail03@gmail.com |
| 004 | Patricia | patriciaemail04@gmail.com |

Travels Table (let's name it like TravelTable)

| ContactID | TripDate | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2022-10-18 | Germany |
| 003 | 2022-02-05 | Canada |
| 001 | 2022-03-07 | EUA |
| 002 | 2022-07-02 | India |
| 004 | 2022-01-28 | Austria |
| 003 | 2022-01-28 | Mexico |

What I need is to catch John's latest trip (To Germany), regardless of what country he's been to. I wrote my SQL like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ContactID, a.Name, a.Email, MAX(b.TripDate) AS 'LastTrip', b.Country
FROM ClientTable a WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN TravelTable b ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID
WHERE a.ContactID IS NOT NULL AND a.Email IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a.ContactID, a.Name, a.Email, b.Country
```

The problem is that I getting this output:

```
| ContactID | Name | Email                 | LastTrip   | Country |
| --------- | ---- | --------------------- | ---------- | ------- |
| 001       | John | johnemail01@gmail.com | 2022-10-18 | Germany |
| 001       | John | johnemail01@gmail.com | 2022-03-07 | EUA     |
```

I really struggle with this one and don't get what I'm not doing to get just the last trip from John.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Bad habits: putting `nolock` everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Thanks for the advice and for the article. It was quite enlightening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the `MAX` date:

```
SELECT 
  a.ContactID, 
  a.Name, 
  a.Email, 
  b.TripDate AS 'LastTrip', 
  b.Country
FROM ClientTable a WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN TravelTable b ON a.ContactID = b.ContactID
WHERE a.ContactID IS NOT NULL 
  AND a.Email IS NOT NULL
  AND b.TripDate = (SELECT MAX(c.TripDate) 
                    FROM TravelTable c)
```

**Result:**

```
| ContactID | Name | Email                 | LastTrip   | Country |
|-----------|------|-----------------------|------------|---------|
| 1         | John | johnemail01@gmail.com | 2022-10-18 | Germany |
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/G5hJaJmI?hide=12).